# Windows Phone 7 gets error c101b000 after downloading 50% from Marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I have developed and published Windows Phone 7 app. Some weeks ago Microsoft updated their Dev Center. After that i've made update for my app. My updated app works good on my test Windows Phone 7 device. But it is impossible to download and install my app on Windows Phone 7 devices - it downoads 50% and then shows error code c101b000. But it is possible to install it on Windows Phone 8 devices. What should i do to fix it?

Maybe should i post a link to app? Or i shouldn't because it will be an ad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote to tech support.
I've send them screenshot and .xap
They've fixed something in marketplace and now everything is OK